# How to add Text animation with vegas.js plugin

Tags: jquery, slide

I am using vegas.js plugin (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation)
for my website. I want to display some texts with those images. how can i add some animated texts with images.
initialize vegas.js in body:

```
<script>
    $("#fullScreenSlide").vegas({
        preload : true,/*load then show image*/
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        shuffle: false,
        cover: true,
        transition: 'fade', /*animation-effect*/
        transitionDuration: 5000, /*animation duration*/
        delay: 12000, /*slide duration*/

    slides: [
      { src: "images/1.jpg" },
      { src: "images/2.jpg" },
      { src: "images/3.jpg" },
      { src: "images/4.jpg" }
    ],
        overlay: 'vegas/overlays/01.png' /*overlay background*/
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fixed this myself.
My solution is this:

```
vegas.js - Add "overlaytext = this._options('overlaytext')," on row 344<br />
vegas.js - Edit row 450 "$inner = $('<div class="vegas-slide-inner"></div>')" to the following "$inner = $('<div class="vegas-slide-inner">' + overlaytext + '</div>')"
```

And your script should be changed to this:

```
<script>
    $(".right-container").vegas({
       slides: [
           { src: "/img/slider1.jpg", overlaytext: "text 1" },
           { src: "/img/slider1.jpg", overlaytext: "text 2" }
       ]
    });
</script>
```

This is to get some text with each image, then you will need to style it to your needs.

Comment: But.. what if the vega.js was updated or the developer uses an minified js? Editing dependency files is not a good practices for web development .

Comment: @DiogoBernardelli You are correct, this could be disastrous - see my answer for a non-dependency injection approach :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than editing the `vegas.js` or `vegas.min.js` dependency files:

Add another parameter to the slides such as `text` or `overlayText`, like so:

```
{ src: "/images/1.jpg", text: "Text for slider 1." },
{ src: "/images/2.jpg", text: "Text for slider 2." }
```

Make sure you create an element with a discernible `id` or `class` such as:

```
<div id="vegasSliderInner"></div>
```

Now just add a `walk` function parameter to your slider, that has an `html` append function.

**(full code):**

```
<script>
    $("#fullScreenSlider").vegas({
        preload : true,/*load then show image*/
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        shuffle: false,
        cover: true,
        transition: 'fade', /*animation-effect*/
        transitionDuration: 5000, /*animation duration*/
        delay: 12000, /*slide duration*/
        overlay: 'vegas/overlays/01.png' /*overlay background*/

        slides: [
            { src: "/images/1.jpg", text: "Text for slider 1." },
            { src: "/images/2.jpg", text: "Text for slider 2." },
            { src: "/images/3.jpg", text: "Text for slider 3." },
            { src: "/images/4.jpg", text: "Text for slider 4." }
        ],

        walk: function (index, slideSettings) {
            $('#vegasSliderInner').html(slideSettings.text);
        }
    });
</script>
```