# Vegas background slideshow new div with animation for every slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have used Vegas slideshow (https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) for 5 slides - every is for about 10 seconds.

But how apply a call "walk" (or other way) if I need to place div with own animation above that slide?

I mean something like a synchro - for every 10 seconds slide with div (text + image with animation) over this slide.
After that new slide and new div with other text and images.

So Vegas would not be only as background slideshow, but as classic slideshow with content.

Any idea or examples?

Comment: you can get your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636515/11527619)