# Vegas Slide - Texte transition

Tags: javascript, transition, slide

I found a post that will answer my question, "How to add text in a Vegas Slide".
cf: [How to add Text animation with vegas.js plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727198/how-to-add-text-animation-with-vegas-js-plugin/58901430#58901430)

But I miss a precision; How to add a "fade" transition to texts?

Thank you.

Comment: Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
walk: function (index, slideSettings) {
$('#vegasSliderInner').hide().html(slideSettings.text).fadeIn(5000);
}
```